# ControlTemplate(Style) binding ItemsSource property

Tags: xaml, data-binding, winrt-xaml

I want to do a data binding in a Style(ControlTemplate) in a ListView

My ListView looks like:

```
<ListView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplate_Selector}" ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource ItemContainerStyle_Selector}"/>
```

Most of properties fetched from ItemsSource are binding in the DataTemplate:

e.g.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="OneOfItem">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <RichTextBlock Grid.Column="0" local:HyperlinkExtensions.Text="{Binding Message}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Time}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

For the reason that there's a area that will be affected by different visual state and there's a property displayed in that area, so I have to binding it in the ItemContainerStyle like:

e.g.

```
<Style x:Key="HeadPicStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">                    
                <Border>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Header" Width="20"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderText" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                            
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveStatesTest">
                            <VisualState x:Name="DefaultStateTest">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideStateChangeThreshold}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowStateTest">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowStateWindowWidth}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Header.Width" Value="100"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>                        
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

On my perspective, the itemContainerStyle is targeted to the itemSource in the ListView, so I can access it's property (means I can directly binding the property name)

However, the HeaderText's text can not be seen in the app.

I'm wondering if my binding in the style is wrong or not?

Comment: In order to see if your binding is working try using a dummy converter on the binding and set a breakpoint in there to see if it is ever being hit.
Also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878189/silverlight-how-to-use-a-binding-in-setter-for-a-style-or-an-equivalent-work-a), although it refers to silverlight might work for you.

Comment: The Style targets a ListViewItem, which has the same DataContext as the ItemTemplate. In fact the control created from the ItemTemplate inherits its DataContext from the containing ListViewItem. So bindings in both ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle go to the same source object, which is the data item, i.e. an element from the ItemsSource collection.

Comment: @Clemens yup! that's what I'm thinking, so I directly binding the property name from the element of ItemsSource collection in my ListViewItem style. But I'm not sure why the property in style not display properly