# Changing FontSize dynamically in windows phone 8.1 application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, resourcedictionary

I need to change application font size dynamically from resource dictionary using slider control

For setting a common font size I just created like this

```
 <x:Double x:Key="VerseFontSize">30</x:Double>
```

And then I called that style in textblock like this

```
<Style x:Key="Title_SubText" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundColorBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource VerseFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5"/>
    </Style>
```

Now I want to increase or decrease the font size using a slider control.

I spend the whole day for making one solution and tried many, but nothing works

Please help me guys to solve this issue.

Comment: have a look at this: [link](http://shloemi.blogspot.in/2011/12/wpf-xaml-example-binding-fontsize-to.html). It may be helpful

Comment: @manoj this is ok, but the problem is I need to set it everywhere in the pages.

Comment: as far as i know using static resource is not a solution, use dynamic resource instead. Bind all font sizes to this VerseFontSize, create a slider that binds two way to VerseFontSize

Answer (score 0):

`DynamicResource` serves this exact purpose in WPF. But it's not available on Windows Phone.

A simple solution is to just bind to a ViewModel in a typical way. As you want this ViewModel to be available across pages, I suggest putting it in application resources. A sample class:

```
public class DynamicResources : ViewModelBase
{
    private double verseFontSize;
    public double VerseFontSize
    {
        get { return verseFontSize; }
        set
        {
            verseFontSize = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The example above uses MVVMLight's ViewModelBase. Then add it to the main `ResourceDictionary` in App.xaml:

```
<local:DynamicResources x:Key="Dynamic" VerseFontSize="30"/>
```

Bind to it in the following way:

```
FontSize="{Binding VerseFontSize, Source={StaticResource Dynamic}}"
```

The problem is that Bindings in Setters aren't available on Windows Phone as well. You can try to do one of the workarounds described here:
[Silverlight: How to use a binding in setter for a style (or an equivalent work around)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878189/silverlight-how-to-use-a-binding-in-setter-for-a-style-or-an-equivalent-work-a)

And modify the value from codebehind like this:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DynamicResources resources = (DynamicResources)App.Current.Resources["Dynamic"];
    resources.VerseFontSize = resources.VerseFontSize + 1;
}
```

As the resource is application-wide, all the pages are updated.